# Asp .Net Core How to reuse Html

Tags: html, asp.net-core

Every single page in my application involves in this basic layout

```
<div class="card custom-card">

<div class="card-header">
    <div class="card-title">
        // icon
        // title
    </div>
</div>

<div class="card-body">

// content here

</div>

<div class="card-footer">

</div>
```

I have used Partial Views and View Components but i have no idea how to actually use them in this situation because i would need to write inside them a lot of different things and that would mean create different partials or components which makes me confused about it.

Comment: Have a read of the documentation, I think it's really well explained; https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use nested layout. Create a new razor view in Shared folder, named it `_LayoutCard.cshtml` (or any name that you prefer), and its content (for example):

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "_LayoutCard";
    Layout = "_Layout";
}

<h1>Layout Card</h1>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">
                    @RenderSection("CardHeader", false)
                </div>
                <div class="card-body">
                    @RenderBody()
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer">
                    @RenderSection("CardFooter", false)
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

notes in the example above:

- make sure you set the `Layout = "_Layout";` to reuse headers and scripts from the main layout
- calling `@RenderBody()` is what makes this layout a nested layout
- `"CardHeader"` and `"CardFooter"` is there so that the view using this layout could specify what the content will be on card header or footer. It is optional of course, you can change the name or even remove it if you need more than 1 nested level (further information below)

as for the example of view using above layout:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
    Layout = "_LayoutCard";
}


@section CardHeader { 
    This is card header
}

this is card body

@section CardFooter { 
    This is card footer
}
```

While `RenderBody` can be called again to create more nested level, `RenderSection` needs to be ignore if not called in the child layout. I'm not sure why this is the case, and it leads to somewhat hacky solution if multiple level nested layout containing `RenderSection` (using `IgnoreSection` or conditional render for example), I suggest limiting to 1 nested layout or avoid `RenderSection` if more than 1 level is needed. Hope it helps.